# GroupBy difference between vb.net and c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I work though a linq tutorial where the code is written in c# and try to translate the snippets into vb.net. The following is working under c#:

```
var employeeGroups = from employee  in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                     group employee by employee.Deptartment;
```

I could translate it into Extension Method

```
Dim group1 = Employee.GetAllEmployees.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Department)
```

which workes fine but

```
Dim group = From emp In Employee.GetAllEmployees
            Group emp By emp.Department
```

gives me a compile error 'into expected'. I couldnt find anything about it but is it right, that I have to use 'INTO' in vb but not in c#? If so, how do I have to adjust my query to fit the c# aquivalent?

Comment: I feel that code translation requires just reading MSDN doc. SO isn't a code translation service...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - he's shown his effort, what's the problem? He's said he can't find anything so trust that he's looked.

Comment: Did you look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx

Comment: `Dim group = From emp In Employee.GetAllEmployees Group By Department = emp.Department Into grp = Group Select grp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.Net has different group syntax. Try this..

```
From emp In Employee.GetAllEmployees
         Group By Department= emp.Department Into g = Group
         Select g
```

Or Simply

```
From emp In Employee.GetAllEmployees
             Group By Department= emp.Department Into Group
```

Comment: You only really need the `Into Group` part.  The group alias and trivial projection are not needed.

Comment: I have working code and clarification about the difference between c# and vb. All I wanted to know. Thanks a lot!